# Failed to enroll admin user "admin": Error: Calling enroll endpoint failed with error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying to run the fabcar-UI code provided [here](https://www.myhsts.org/hyperledger-fabric-book/) using 2 org (1 peer each) network using docker swarm network on AWS. 2 Orderer services are running on peer0.org1. I am able to run peer chaincode invoke command successfully from the terminal. After integrating the fabcar-ui I am running into below error when registering the admin. Can someone please guide me?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-11-233:~/hlf-docker-swarm/fabcar-ui$ node app
fabcar-ui listening on port 3000
Wallet path: /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/fabcar-ui/wallet
2022-03-12T05:49:09.886Z - error: [FabricCAClientService.js]: Failed to enroll admin, error:%o message=Calling enroll endpoint failed with error [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ca.org1.example.com ca.org1.example.com:7054], stack=Error: Calling enroll endpoint failed with error [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ca.org1.example.com ca.org1.example.com:7054]
    at ClientRequest.request.on (/home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/fabcar-ui/node_modules/fabric-ca-client/lib/FabricCAClient.js:327:19)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19), errno=ENOTFOUND, code=ENOTFOUND, syscall=getaddrinfo, hostname=ca.org1.example.com, host=ca.org1.example.com, port=7054
Failed to enroll admin user "admin": Error: Calling enroll endpoint failed with error [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ca.org1.example.com ca.org1.example.com:7054]
Failed to enroll admin user "admin": Error: Calling enroll endpoint failed with error [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ca.org1.example.com ca.org1.example.com:7054]
```

[image]

Since this is related to fabric CA, I am providing the docker-compose file for CA Org1.

```
services:
  ca_org1:
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.name == manager
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/fabric-ca/org1:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    container_name: ca_org1
    networks:
       test:
         aliases:
          - ca.org1.example.com
```

Comment: try this: if anywhere in fabric ui code you are using "ca.org1.example.com:8080" change this to "0.0.0.0:8080"

Comment: @Rajan UI code doesn't use   "ca.org1.example.com:8080". 

Its basically the same code you find on fabric official doc in enrollAdmin.js. I am running into error when `const enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: 'admin', enrollmentSecret: 'adminpw' });` is getting executed. Really appreciate if you could help me with this issue as I am very much new to fabric

Comment: print and show value of "caInfo" variable

Comment: @Rajan Here is the output caInfo https://ibb.co/NTpDj1G

Comment: @Rajan issue is solved. After containerising the UI application it’s working now the registration and the enrolment. However I am running other issues when invoke and query. I will open separate issue for that.